# form for validation and open link in same page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web-deployment

Here I use HTML and javascript please go through it don't want to change my whole code but just take a look.
there is an HTML file and a javascript file.
both are linked.
in a form, I am taking user name and password and checking or validating them if they are right I will let the user go to the next page or stop it there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGIN</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #error{
            color:red;
            font-style: italic;
        }
        #success{
            color:green;
            font-style:italic;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" onsubmit = "return(validateForm());">
    Enter username : <input id='username' type='text' required>
    Enter password : <input id='password' type='password' required>
    <p id="error"></p>
    <p id="sucess"></p>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Login" />

</form>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src="functions.js"></script>
</html>



var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

function validateForm(){
    if (username == 'username' && password == 'password'){
        document.getElementById('sucess').innerHTML = 'sucessful login';
        return true;

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'invalid credentials';

        return false;

    }

}

function welcomeuser(){
        document.getElementById('welcomemsg').innerHTML('Welcome ' +username);
    }
```

Comment: for form validation, you can use jquery validation plugin

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution

**functions.js code as below**

```
function validateForm(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    if (username == 'username' && password == 'password'){
        document.getElementById('sucess').innerHTML = 'sucessful login';
        // redirect code in page
        // window.location.href = 'thankyou.html'
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'invalid credentials';
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Your HTML code as below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGIN</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #error{
            color:red;
            font-style: italic;
        }
        #success{
            color:green;
            font-style:italic;
        }
    </style>
<script type='text/javascript' src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    Enter username : <input id='username' type='text'>
    Enter password : <input id='password' type='password'>
    <p id="error"></p>
    <p id="sucess"></p>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Login" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work since you still submitting the form... change input type to `button`

Comment: @A.Meshu please check the question first he wants to display the message on the same page or redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are submitting the form (using `type=submit`) your form skips the javascript validation. A quick fix is to change:

```
<input type = "submit" value = "Login" />
```

To:

```
<input type = "button" value = "Login" />
```

And you don't need this: `onsubmit = "return(validateForm());"` just call the function onclick or with event listener

Of course you need to get the values from the function in order to check it,
And then after checking if inputs are correct here:

```
if (username == 'username' && password == 'password'){
```

To do whatever you want (either redirect the user of actually submitting the form using `submit()` method).

I modify your code little and this should work:

```js
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', validateForm);

function validateForm(){
  var username = document.querySelector('#username').value;
  var password = document.querySelector('#password').value;
  if (username === 'username' && password === 'password') {
    document.querySelector('#sucess').textContent = 'sucessful login';
    // redirect or submit 
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector('#error').textContent = 'invalid credentials';    
  }
}
```

```css
#error{color:red; font-style: italic; }
#success{ color:green; font-style:italic; }
```

```html
<form method="post">
    Enter username : <input id='username' type='text' required>
    Enter password : <input id='password' type='password' required>
    <p id="error"></p>
    <p id="sucess"></p>
    <button id="submit" type="button">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if we add the return false then form not submitted.